# „Vor kurzem“ vs „in letzter Zeit“

Tags: word-usage, difference

Ich habe einen Aufsatz über meinen Aufenthalt in Österreich geschrieben, wobei ich „in letzter Zeit *X* gemacht“ schrieb. Ich bin vor ungefähr fünf Monaten aus Österreich weggeflogen.

„In letzter Zeit“ wurde zu „vor kurzem“ korrigiert.

Ich verstehe, dass es unterschiedlichen Zeitrahmen für z.B *bald* und *gleich* gibt, aber was ist der Unterschied des Zeitrahmens bezüglich „in letzter Zeit“ und „vor kurzem“?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Vor kurzem habe ich *Game of Thrones* gesehen

= ich habe eine Folge gesehen (oder vielleicht eine ganze Staffel auf einmal).

> In letzter Zeit habe ich *Game of Thrones* gesehen

= ich habe regelmäßig jeden Mittwoch die aktuelle Episode gesehen.

Der Unterschied liegt also im *Aspekt* der Aussage (perfektiv vs. iterativ) – es ist derselbe Unterschied, der im Englischen durch Verbformen ausgedrückt wird (*I watched …* vs. *I’ve been watching …*) Im Deutschen wird dagegen *nicht* die Verbform zur Unterscheidung benutzt (beide Konstruktionen stehen im Perfekt), sondern adverbiale Erweiterungen.

Comment: So how we recognize,realize if a sentence "perfektiv" or "iterativ", i mean "in letzter Zeit" does make always a sentence that it is _perfektiv_ or is there a specific clues for both _perfektiv_ and _iterativ?_

Comment: @user1474062 The difference is that "in letzter Zeit" is used for events that happened repeatedly or continuously. It is often (but not necessarily) used to indicate that some behavior has changed.

Answer (score 3):

Es kommt weniger auf die Zeit, die vergangen ist, sondern ob das Ereignis abgeschlossen ist oder nicht:

> In letzter Zeit war ich öfters in Österreich. (mehrmals)
>   Vor kurzem war ich in Österreich. (ich beziehe mich auf ein Ereignis)

Comment: Der Begriff „abgeschlossen“ trifft es m.E. nicht, aber ansonsten ist die Erklärung richtig.